# How can I fully reset keyboard settings if my on screen keyboard doesn't work?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 18.10

I sought out advice on how to fix my keyboard, because it did not always work after being in sleep mode, so I came across this solution:

```
dmesg | grep i8042
```

and confirm you get this output

```
[ 1.514469] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBC,PNP0f13:MOUE] at      0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[ 1.525273] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[ 1.525287] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[ 1.526035] input: AT Raw Set 2 keyboard as     /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[ 21.927438] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as    /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input10
then, add the boot parameters i8042.direct and i8042.dumbkbd to    /etc/default/grub. For example, run

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that begins GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= and edit it to include the new parameters, so that after your edit it looks something like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"
```

Save by pressing Ctrl+O, exit by pressing Ctrl+X, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

BUT now my keyboard is completely useless. Doesn't work at all, and the on screen keyboard works EXCEPT the letter "d" so I can't even type "sudo". Please help my reset my keyboard settings or even just reset Ubuntu all together.